# Flutter : EngineIOException: websocket error

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I am trying to connect to my socket io server by **adhara flutter library**. According [official suggestion](https://pub.dev/packages/adhara_socket_io) after adding to yaml file in project i write this code to connect to my socket server:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    manager = SocketIOManager();
    initSocket();
  }

  initSocket() async {
    SocketIO socket =
        await manager.createInstance(SocketOptions('https://socket.******.ir'));
    socket.onConnect((data) {
      debugPrint("connected...");
      debugPrint(data);
    });
    socket.onConnectError((er) {
      debugPrint('onConnectError: $er');
    });
    socket.onConnectTimeout((er) {
      debugPrint('onConnectTimeout: $er');
    });
    socket.onError((er) {
      debugPrint('onError: $er');
    });
    socket.onDisconnect((er) {
      debugPrint('onDisconnect: $er');
    });
    socket.connect();
  }
```

But after running i got this error:

```
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/flutter ( 6791): onConnectError: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error
I/flutter ( 6791): onConnectError: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error
I/flutter ( 6791): onConnectError: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error
I/flutter ( 6791): onConnectError: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error
I/flutter ( 6791): onConnectError: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error
```

For sure that socket server works correctly i am using **socket.io tester chrome extention** and this is it's results:

[image]

As you can see i send a message on **test** event and i received those message so the server works correctly.

I also added add **android:useCleartextTraffic="true"**
inside the application tag of **AndroidManifest.xml**.

What is flutter problem?

Comment: Have solved this problem ?

Comment: It was beacasue of ssl certificate problem@yifan_z

Comment: Hello, have you solved this problem?

Comment: It was beacasue of ssl certificate problem @KevvKeka

Comment: @CyrustheGreat how did u solve with that ssl problem?

Comment: If I right remember, It was `certificate problem` that was related server stuff. @Mr.Jay

Comment: @CyrustheGreat ty for replying, my certificate seems to be right as IOS is able to connect it just an issue w android.

Comment: Lets try on Http to see you'r problem is fixed or not ?@Mr.Jay

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any issues on the setup configured in the Flutter app. I suggest checking the endpoint that the app connects to. Common causes are the SSL configured in the server which causes the websocket error.